# Passing an Object to Function Within Same Scope Slow?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Does passing around an object within the same scope cost any appreciable delay? Consider Option 1 and Option 2 below. In the first option I just work with the object directly. Option 2 is the better practice for encapsulation, but let's say I do it within the same scope anyway - is this any slower (assume huge arrays of objects with hundreds of properties)?

```
var sampleObject = {id:2, objString = 'something'};
```

Option 1:

```
function addPropToObject(){
 sampleObject.someNewProp = 'lalala'
}
```

Option 2:

```
function addPropToObject(obj){
 obj.someNewProp = 'lalala'
}

addPropToObject(sampleObject);
```

AngularJs tag is just there in case there is a difference if the function was:

```
$scope.adPropToObject = function(){....
```

Though imo it shouldn't matter at all. Feel free to change the title if you can think of a better one.

Comment: This depends on implementation, but if the variable is already available in the same scope, there's not much use in passing it as an argument.

Comment: I understand that (as noted in the question), this is more of a hypothetical question.

Comment: The runtime cost of accessing a variable in an outer scope is very small and possible zero in a modern runtime. It's absolutely not worth worrying about.

Comment: Thanks pointy, that's good to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on how the JS engine is implemented. Option 1 may be slower since it has to move up one (or more) scopes to find `sampleObject`. Option 2 may be slower because it has to push `sampleObject` onto the stack and pull it off when accessing `obj`. You could write a [jsPerf](https://jsperf.com/) and test response times yourself.

Comment: I don't really have any particular application for this - I just find myself writing everything using option 2 "for clarity" and under the assumption that I will be moving the options out into helper methods, so I was wondering if there is some rule that always applies. Seems like there is not, I appreciate your answer.